# I want to decompile only xml files from apk without disturbing resources

Tags: android

How to decompile specific files from apk file? I want to get only xml files decrypted without disturbing other code / resources.

Comment: u can decompile  apk file and get all xml file and so on file

Comment: [Online APK  Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

Comment: @nobalG, "Status: Error" :-(

Answer (score 0):

By using Dex 2 Jar you can back track the apk file to the code. But you will not able to see the native code completly or also you wont be able to see the C code. But atleast you can see the xml file when its loaded in  jd-jui.

*Note: Its not a good ethics for programmers if you are trying to peek in to other source code or other project files. Good programmers never do unethical hacks. So use the resources with good intentions.*

Answer (score 0):

Use apkTool to fulfill your needs. Decompiling only xmls are possible with the "-s" flag. The process won't disturb your original resources in any means, only those XML files will be decompiled to a much more readable form. You can recompile the project with apkTool too.